# Linux Can't play sound at the begining of system start in an auto-start process using SDL_Mixer

Tags: c++, linux, audio, ubuntu-16.04, sdl-2

I've used SDL2_Mixer to play sound on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.
Here is my class code.

```cpp
bool SoundPlayer::init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
    {
        LOG(ERROR)<<"init failed.\n";
    }

    LOG(INFO)<<"Speaker SDL init succeeded.";

    volume = DEFAULT_VOLUME;

    if(Mix_OpenAudio(MIX_DEFAULT_FREQUENCY, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096) == -1)
    {
        LOG(ERROR)<<"audio not found,"<<Mix_GetError();    
        is_init = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_init = true;
    }
    return is_init;
}
```

**Starting Procedure**

- Process A staticly declared a SoundPlayer class.
- Process A is started by another Process B.
- Process B is started by system process management tool `supervisord` right after system start.

**Problem Description**

- Right after system started, process A cound not play sound successfully, coming with `ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory`.
- However, after I login my system remotely with teamviewer, the sound plays good. Process A never restarted but `SoundPlayer` class inited again
- Another scenario is, after system started, when I compiled a test program to play sound and mannually started it in a terminal, the sound plays good too.

I'm so confused and wondering if I missed something after system start or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one responds, but I got the solution.
I was confused before because I didn't know what system did when I logged on ubuntu with teamviewer. Now I know, I just enter the desktop system with a user.

I use `SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(0,0)` to show audio devices.
Before I log in, it returned `dummy output`. After I log in, it returned `Built-in analog output`. So that's the reason.

To solve this, I turn on the **Auto-login** function and it works well.

Comment: May someone help me explain this for me? A privilege issue? Thanks a lot.